# Ruby - Iterating over a Nested Hash and counting values

Tags: ruby, hash, nested

Despite there being many questions on nested hashes I've not found any solutions to my problem.

I'm pulling in strings and matching each character to a hash like so:

```
numberOfChars = {}
string.each_char do |c|
    RULES.each do |key, value|
        if c === key
            numberOfChars[value] += 1
        end
    end
end
```

This worked fine and would output something like "a appears 3 times" until I realised that my hash needed to be nested, akin to this:

```
RULES = {
    :limb {
        :colour {
            'a' => 'foo',
            'b' => 'bar'
        },         
        'c' => 'baz'
    }
}
```

So how would I go about getting the 'leaf' key and it's value?

While it's iterating over the hash it also needs to count how many times each key appears, e.g. does 'a' appear more than 'b'? If so add a to new hash. But I'm pretty lost as to how that would work in practice without knowing how it'll be iterating over a nested hash to begin with.

It just seems to me an overly convoluted way of doing this but if anyone's got any pointers they'd be hugely appreciated!

Also, if it's not painfully clear already I'm new to Ruby so I'm probably making some fundamental mistakes.

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? (ruby -v) Ruby complains when I try to use your RULES example.

Comment: See the example below. You're missing a comments in your RULES setup.

Comment: @NoahClark I'm using 1.9.2, you're right though, I did miss out a comma in that example, I've edited it to include it.

Comment: The reason I thought it might be complaining is because we were using a different version of ruby. 1.9 different than previous versions. If the answer below answers your question you should accept it. If you don't people will be less likely to answer your questions in the future.

Comment: Have you tried using recursion? That will get you access to leaf nodes at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
RULES = {
  :limb => {
    :colour => {
      'a' => 'foo',
      'b' => 'bar'
    },
    'c' => 'baz',
    :color => {
      'b' => 'baz'
    }
  }
}

def count_letters(hash, results = {})
  hash.each do |key, value|
    if value.kind_of?(Hash)
      count_letters(value, results)
    else
      results[key] = (results[key] || 0) + 1
    end
  end
  results
end

p count_letters(RULES)
```

Comment: Hi @TuteC, thanks very much for your fast reply! I've implemented and tweaked it a bit, yours counts the number of times a character appears in a hash whereas I need it to _compare_ a character against the value in a hash (so if character == key), and if it does then count it, then get the totals. I'm confident your solution is a step in the right direction but not quite there. I'll spend the next day or so working on it :) Cheers!